Representing Machine Learning in Mathematical Language
Consider a generic (univariate) time series model:
$$ \hat{y}(x_n, \ldots, x_{n+h-1} \mid x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}; \boldsymbol{\theta}) $$
Where:
$$ \hat{y}_{t+h} \text{ is the forecast for the next } h \text{ time points} $$
$$ \boldsymbol{\theta} = (\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_k) \text{ is the vector of model parameters} $$
$$ x_t, x_{t-1}, \ldots, x_{t-p} \text{ are the } p \text{ most recent observations} $$
The way I see it, there are two ways (Static vs Dynamic) to perform (Rolling Window) Cross Validation in this setting. I am trying to represent Cross Validation in mathematical language

Static Approach:


Step 1: Here, we fit a single model (e.g ARIMA) to first $n$ points (i.e. 0 to $n$)
Step 2: Then, we use this model from Step 1 to forecast the next $h$ points (i.e. $n+1$ to $n+h$) in a row (in one shot) and record the error
Step 3: We then give the model the true information all the way to the $n+h$ point and again make it forecast $h$ more points, record the error etc.

Mathematically, we can represent this idea as follows:
$$ \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}} = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \sum_{i=1}^n L(y_i, \hat{y}(x_i \mid x_0, \ldots, x_{i-1}; \boldsymbol{\theta})) $$
For forecasts:
$$ \text{For } t = n, n+h, \ldots, T-h: $$
$$ \hat{y}_{t+h} = \hat{y}(x_{t+h} \mid x_0, \ldots, x_t; \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}) $$
$$ e_{t+h} = y_{t+h} - \hat{y}_{t+h} $$

Dynamic Approach:


Step 1: Here, we fit a model (e.g ARIMA) to first $n$ points (i.e. 0 to $n$)
Step 2: Then, we use this model from Step 1 to forecast the next $h$ points (i.e. $n+1$ to $n+h$) in a row (in one shot) and record the error
Step 3: We re-fit the same type model (e.g. ARIMA) from 0 to $n+h$, and make the model predict again the next $h$ points, etc
Step 4: In the future, we will forecast using the model built on the complete set of data available to us.

Mathematically, we can represent this idea as follows:
$$ \text{For each time step } t = n, n+h, \ldots, T-h: $$
$$ \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_t = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \sum_{i=t-n+1}^t L(y_i, \hat{y}(x_i \mid x_{t-n+1}, \ldots, x_{i-1}; \boldsymbol{\theta})) $$
$$ \hat{y}_{t+h} = \hat{y}(x_{t+h} \mid x_{t-n+1}, \ldots, x_t; \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_t) $$
$$ e_{t+h} = y_{t+h} - \hat{y}_{t+h} $$
In both approaches:
$$ L(\cdot) \text{ is a loss function (e.g., squared error)} $$
$$ n \text{ is the size of the initial training window or rolling window} $$
$$ e_{t+h} \text{ is the forecast error} $$
$$ T \text{ is the total number of time points} $$
As we can see,

In the static approach, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ is computed once using the initial $n$ observations and then used for all subsequent forecasts. The model uses all historical data $(x_0, \ldots, x_t)$ for each forecast. This is computationally more efficient as the model fitting process only happens once. This approach is testing the performance of a "single model". However, I think this approach is less optimal because we only build a model on limited data.

In the dynamic approach, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}_t$ is recomputed at each time step $t$ using the most recent $n$ observations. The model uses only the most recent $n$ observations $(x_{t-n+1}, \ldots, x_t)$ for each forecast. This is computationally less efficient as the model fitting process only happens many times. This approach is testing the performance of a "class of models". However, I think this approach is more robust as it generalizes the idea of the model better. I.e. in the future, how reliable will ARIMA be in general. This approach can also improve the performance of the model as it allows it to use more information for parameter estimation, and allows the model to adapt/recalibrate itself in the presence of new data/trends


I tried to represent my understanding of both approaches visually:

Can someone please tell me if my mathematical representations of these approaches are correct?
Thanks!
PS: I also tried to write an R function to represent Approach 2:
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(123)


#n <- 100: length of the time series to 100 observations, it means that the generated time series will have 100 data points.
#h <- 5: T forecast horizon to 5 : model will predict 5 steps ahead in the future. E.g, if the current time point #is ( t ), the model will forecast #the value at ( t+5 ).
#frequency <- 52: This sets the frequency of simulated time series to 52.
#window_size <- 52: size of the rolling window to 52. the model will use the most recent 52 observations to train the model #at each step. E.g.
#if the current time point is ( t ), the model will use the data from ( t-51 ) to ( t ) to make the forecast.

n <- 100
h <- 5
frequency <- 52
window_size <- 52
##################################

time_series <- arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.8), n = n) + 10 + 0.5 * (1:n)

ts_data <- ts(time_series, frequency = frequency)

# Rolling window cross-validation function
rolling_cv <- function(data, h = 1, window_size = 52) {
    n <- length(data)
    forecasts <- numeric(n - window_size - h + 1)
    actual <- numeric(n - window_size - h + 1)
    
    for (i in 1:(n - window_size - h + 1)) {
        train <- data[i:(i + window_size - 1)]
        test <- data[i + window_size + h - 1]
        
        model <- auto.arima(train)
        forecast <- forecast(model, h = h)
        
        forecasts[i] <- forecast$mean[h]
        actual[i] <- test
    }
    
    return(list(forecasts = forecasts, actual = actual))
}

# Perform rolling window cross-validation
cv_results <- rolling_cv(ts_data, h = h, window_size = window_size)

errors <- cv_results$actual - cv_results$forecasts
percent_errors <- 100 * errors / cv_results$actual

plot_data <- data.frame(
    Time = (1:(length(cv_results$actual))) + window_size + h - 1,
    Actual = cv_results$actual,
    Forecast = cv_results$forecasts,
    Error = errors,
    PercentError = percent_errors
)

p1 <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Time)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Actual, color = "Actual")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Forecast, color = "Forecast")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Actual" = "blue", "Forecast" = "red")) +
    labs(title = "Actual vs Forecast", y = "Value") +
    theme_minimal()

p2 <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Time, y = Error)) +
    geom_line(color = "green") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
    labs(title = "Forecast Errors", y = "Error") +
    theme_minimal()

p3 <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Time, y = PercentError)) +
    geom_line(color = "purple") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
    labs(title = "Forecast Percent Errors", y = "Percent Error") +
    theme_minimal()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1, heights = c(3, 3, 3))

mae <- mean(abs(errors))
rmse <- sqrt(mean(errors^2))
mape <- mean(abs(percent_errors))

cat("Mean Absolute Error:", mae, "\n")
cat("Root Mean Square Error:", rmse, "\n")
cat("Mean Absolute Percentage Error:", mape, "%\n")



Might be better suited on Cross Validated...

The mathematical representations do not match your text description. I'll first put down the math and then my thoughts on your arguments about the performance comparison between these two approaches.

Approach 1 (single model). Suppose we use $m\times h$ target values for training, then it should be
$$ \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}} = \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \sum_{i=n}^{n+m-1} L\left(\mathbf{y}_i, \hat{\mathbf{y}}_i(\mathbf{x}_{i-1}; \boldsymbol{\theta})\right),$$
where $\mathbf{x}_{i-1}=[x_{i-1},\dots x_{i-n}]$, $\mathbf{y}_i = [y_i,\dots, y_{i+h-1}]$ and similar for $\hat{\mathbf{y}}_i$.

For forecasting, $ t = n, n+h, \ldots, n+Th:$
$$ \hat{\mathbf{y}}_{t} = \hat{\mathbf{y}}_t(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}; \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}) $$
$$ \mathbf{e}_{t} = \mathbf{y}_{t} - \hat{\mathbf{y}}_{t}$$

Approach 2 (dynamic models). If we stick with the illustrating figure (does not match the text description), then we train a series of models online, with increasing input size. So, the inputs should be denote as $\mathbf{x}_{i-1} = [x_{i-1},\dots,x_0]$ for each training.

Regarding performance, conceptually, dynamic model approach is better since we embed more data and most recent information into training. This is important, especially for long-term forecasting and/or when data have distribution drifting. However, there is probably no theoretical way to prove it.
